# Autocomplete : Search for default term

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using Jquery Autocomplete for search on my website. If I type `god` in the box, it returns

```
The Godfather
The Godfather II
The Godfather III
```

If I select any of the 3 values, it should go to the movie's page (`movies.jsp`). But if I press enter without selecting, it should go the search page(`GetSearchResults.jsp`) and list all results that match my query.

I tried putting a condition to detect `e.keycode==13` for enter, but that engulfs even the case when i select `The Godfather`, coz the textbox doesnt lose focus while navigating through the values. Here's my code :

```
$(function(){
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/Search.jsp",
        minLength: 3,
        html: true,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
                window.location.href="/movies.jsp?productId="+ui.item.id;
        },
    });
})
$("#search").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13 && $(this).is(":focus")){
        var term = $(this).val();
        window.open('/GetSearchResults.jsp?type=all&term='+term, '_self');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the focus is your only concern you can remove it with [jQuery.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/):

`$(this).blur();`